# Linear order on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I know that the $\mathbb{C}$ -- non-ordered field. And the answer that I have, that $i^2 < 0$. But in axioms of order field I see only this:

1. $\forall a,b,c$, if $a \leq b \Rightarrow a+c \leq b+c$
2. If $0 \leq a$ and $0 \leq b \Rightarrow 0 \leq ab$

I think, that this follows from 2., but how? $i \leq 0$ or $0 \leq i$?

If $0 \leq i \Rightarrow i^2 \leq 0$, if $i \leq 0 \Rightarrow i^2 \leq 0$, but how this axioms follows, that for all numbers in ordered field must be true that: if $a,b \leq 0 \Rightarrow 0 \leq ab$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiom "$0\leq a$ and $0\leq b$ implies $0\leq ab$" together with other ordered field axioms implies this
\begin{align}a,b\leq 0 &\implies a+(-a)\leq 0 + (-a)\ \text{and}\ b+(-b)\leq 0+(-b)\\ &\implies -a,-b\geq 0 \implies (-a)(-b) \geq 0 \implies ab\geq 0.\end{align}

Thus, if you take linear order on $\mathbb C$, either $i\geq 0$ or $i\leq 0$, but both imply $i^2\geq 0$.

---

So, how does this prove that $\mathbb C$ is not an ordered field? Well, in any ordered field we have $-1\not\geq 0$. Assume the contrary, $-1\geq 0$. Now, it follows that $(-1)^2 \geq 0$ and $-1+1\geq 0 + 1$, i.e. $1\geq 0$ and $0 \geq 1$. Thus, $1=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: I cannot understand implication $\Rightarrow -a,-b \geq 0$

Comment: @Arsenii, calculate $a+ (-a)$ and $0+(-a)$.

Comment: oh, ye, I am sorry :D

Comment: @Arsenii, everything ok :) Do you know how to prove that $-1\not\geq 0$ in any ordered field?

Comment: If $F$ -- ordered field, and $1_F$ -- mult.identity element must be true, that $1_F \neq 0$. The $-1_F$ -- inverse element for $1_F$ in add.group so $\Rightarrow -1_F + 1_F = 0$ . If $-1_F \geq 0 \Rightarrow -1_F + 1_F \geq 0$, but $-1_F + 1_F = 0 \Rightarrow$ that $-1_F = 1_F = 0$, but this is false because $1_F \neq 0$. Yes?

Comment: There is no contradiction in $0\geq 0$. How do you go from $-1\geq 0$ to $-1+1\geq 0$? I'll edit my answer, @Arsenii.

Comment: I am think that $-1 + 1\geq 0$ and $-1 +1 \geq 0 +1$ (because $-1 \geq 0$) $\Rightarrow$ $-1 = 1 = 0$, no? And I see the edition, yes, thx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85374/discussion-between-ennar-and-arsenii).